# Distributional convergence and expectations

Tags: expectation, weak-convergence

I'm struggling with the following problem. Let $X_n$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables which are finite almost surely and all with expectation 1. Assume they converge in distribution against some other random variable $X$. Show that $X$ has expectation smaller or equal 1.

I first thought that Fatou would help, but this is only helpful for the almost everywhere convergence, isn't it?

Thank you in advance,

Fischaaa

Comment: One option would be to use the fact that convergence in distribution implies almost sure convergence for some random variables distributed like the first ones. Ever saw this result?

Comment: I found this in Wikipedia: "Almost sure representation. Usually, convergence in distribution does not imply convergence almost surely. However for a given sequence {Xn} which converges in distribution to X0 it is always possible to find a new probability space (Ω, F, P) and random variables {Yn, n = 0, 1, ...} defined on it such that Yn is equal in distribution to Xn for each n ≥ 0, and Yn converges to Y0 almost surely." Is this the statement you are referring to? In that case I could directly apply Fatou, right?

Comment: @Fischaaa could you provide a link to it?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables

Comment: "Is this the statement you are referring to?" Yes. "In that case I could directly apply Fatou, right?" Yes. (Well done...)

Answer (score 1):

We have for any non-negative random variable $Y$ that 
$$\mathbb E\left[Y\right]=\int_0^{+\infty}\mathbb P\left(\left\{Y\gt t\right\}\right)\mathrm dt.$$
Define $f_n(t) :=\mathbb P\left(\left\{X_n\gt t\right\}\right)$ and 
$f(t) :=\mathbb P\left(\left\{X\gt t\right\}\right)$ on $[0,+\infty)$ (that we endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and Lebesgue measure $\lambda$). By the convergence in distribution of $\left(X_n\right)_{ n\geqslant 1}$ to $X$, we have $f_n(t)\to f(t)$ at each point of continuity of $f$. The set of discontinuity points of $f$ is at most countable, hence $f_n(t)\to f(t)$ for $\lambda$-almost every $t$. Now we can conclude from Fatou's lemma.

Comment: Nice alternative!